# Google People API Field parameter not working

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

There seems to be issue with the google people api.

If you go to the following link to test out the api,
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.connections.list

try:

GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?sortOrder=FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING&fields=connections(emailAddresses%2Cnames)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The results does not display the email address of the contact even thou it is specified in the fields.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1):

You want to supply the [requestMask](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/RequestMask) parameter and ask for the email addresses and names explicitly:

This updated query should work:

https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?sortOrder=FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING&requestMask.includeField=person.emailAddresses,person.names&fields=connections(emailAddresses%2Cnames)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}